# As3 FileReference download dynamic url

Tags: actionscript-3, download, action, filereference

As3 FileReference download dynamic url not send variable data;
Sample:

```
downloadXls.buttonMode=true;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.events.Event;

var localRef:FileReference;
var fileRequest:URLRequest= new URLRequest("http://[sitename].com/xlsexport.php?id=456");
downloadXls.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,downloadXlsH);
function downloadXlsH(event:MouseEvent):void{
    localRef = new FileReference();
    localRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    localRef.download( fileRequest, 'myfile.xls' );
}
function completeHandler(e:Event):void{
    trace('OK. Dosya Kaydedildi.');
}
```

PROBLEM: http://[sitename].com/xls.php?id=456   id variable not send xlsexport.php

Code is just "filename = xlsexport" variable produces a variable I want to send a different "id = 4545 & pass = 87665"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want by using URLVariables class.

Create an ActionScript 3 Class File (*.as) and paste following codes in it:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;

    public class Download extends Sprite
    {
        var localRef:FileReference;
        var urlVars:URLVariables;
        var fileRequest:URLRequest;

        public function Download(downloadXls:*)
        {
            downloadXls.buttonMode=true;
            downloadXls.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,downloadXlsH);
        }

        private function downloadXlsH(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            localRef = new FileReference();
            localRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

            urlVars = new URLVariables();
            urlVars.id = 456;

            fileRequest = new URLRequest();
            fileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
            fileRequest.data = urlVars;
            fileRequest.url = "http://[sitename].com/xlsexport.php";

            localRef.download(fileRequest);
        }

        private function completeHandler(e:Event):void
        {
            trace('OK. Dosya Kaydedildi.');
        }
    }
}
```

And use following line for call it in timeline of your Adobe Flash project (*.fla file).

```
import Temp_Example4;
var temp:Temp_Example4 = new Temp_Example4(downloadXls);
```

Remember that if you want to add more than one URL variable, you must use following line of code for each one of your URL variables:

```
nameOfYourURLVariablesInstance.yourUrlVariableName = yourUrlVariableValue;
```

something like this:

```
urlVars.id = 456;
```

in sample ActionScript 3 Class File.

Also, you can download a sample project from following addresses:

[4Shared -> Sample Project](http://www.4shared.com/zip/VIewMZMc/Example_4.html)

[SendSpace -> Sample Project](http://www.sendspace.com/file/r6s56p)

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing the URL as a string.

```
var _id:int = 456;
var _pass:int = 87665;
var _requestString:String = "http://" + sitename + ".com/xlsexport.php?id=" + _id + "&pass=" + _pass;

var fileRequest:URLRequest= new URLRequest(_requestString);
```

PS. Also make sure you're using the same var name (sitename or filename).

Comment: Does not work.
localRef.download( fileRequest, 'myfile.xls' );
fileRequest not send variable